# Redis adding invalid characters to key names

Tags: php, redis, lumen, predis

We're using Redis across two different servers:

One has PHPRedis, using IGBINARY as the serialiser.

```
PHP 7.2.x

redis

Redis Support => enabled
Redis Version => 3.1.1
Available serializers => php, igbinary
```

The other is using Lumen with predis (again with IGBinary).

```
PHP 7.3.x

redis

Redis Support => enabled
Redis Version => 5.3.4
Available serializers => php, json,igbinary
```

When retrieving keys via Redis->zRange  on the first server we get correct info:

[1287871]=>  float(23)
[1299984]=>  float(23)

On the second server, we get (there’s actually strange characters preceding the key name)

[  1287871]=>  float(23)
[   1299984]=>  float(23)

Both are accessed with the same key, so there must be a difference with the client I presume? How can we get the second server working like the first?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to the serializer not being set as IGBINARY on the Lumen server. Seems the documented 'serializer' param in the config doesn't work